# Less verbose conditional implementation

Tags: scala

I am brand new to coding and I am learning with Scala. My exercise is below but I have a feeling my code is way too verbose. How can I improve it?

Exercise:

*Internet telephony service providers offer calling services between computers and regular phones not connected to the Internet. Write a script to help people determine what their calling costs would be based on how many minutes they expect to talk in a month, whether they will be using a monthly subscription or pay-as-you-go service, what country they will be making those calls to and whether they will be making calls to both mobile and landline phones or just to a landline phone. Use the following information to help you with your task:

[image: Table showing rates]

Lewis, Mark C.; Lacher, Lisa. Introduction to Programming and Problem-Solving Using Scala, Second Edition (Chapman & Hall/CRC Textbooks in Computing) (Page 74). CRC Press. Kindle Edition.*

```
import scala.io.StdIn._

object callingCost {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
//user input
  print("Will you be using (1)Monthly or (2)Pay-As-You-Go ")
  val planType = readInt()
  print("What country will you be calling? ")
  val country = readLine()
  print("How many minutes would you talk per month? ")
  val minsMonth = readInt()
  print("Will you be calling both Mobile and Landlines as opposed to just landlines? (Y/N) ")
  val lineType = readLine()
//declare monthly subscription cost per country
  val chinaCost120 = 1.19
  val chinaCost400 = 3.89
  val chinaCost800 = 7.79
  val chinaUnltd = 13.99
  val indiaCost120 = 1.42
  val indiaCost800 = 8.99
  val indiaUnltd = 19.99
  val ukMobLand = 2.09
  val ukLand = 1.19
  val mexicoUnltd = 1.79
  val usaUnltd = 2.99
  //declare pay as you go cost per country
  val chinaPaygI = 0.02
  val indiaPaygI = 0.015
  val usaPaygI = 0.023
  val mexicoPaygMl = 0.035
  val mexicoPaygL = 0.01
  val ukPaygMl = 0.10
  val ukPaygL = 0.023
//monthly plan evaluation
  val cost = if (planType == 1) {
    if (country == "China") {
      if (minsMonth <= 120) chinaCost120
      else if (minsMonth > 120 && minsMonth <= 400) chinaCost400
      else if (minsMonth > 400 && minsMonth <= 800) chinaCost800
      else chinaUnltd
    }
    else if (country == "India") {
      if (minsMonth <= 120) indiaCost120
      else if (minsMonth > 120 && minsMonth <= 800) indiaCost800
      else indiaUnltd
    }
    else if (country == "UK") {
      if (lineType == "Y") ukMobLand
      else ukLand
    }
    else if (country == "Mexico") mexicoUnltd else usaUnltd
} else { //Pay-As-You-Go section
  if (country == "China") minsMonth*chinaPaygI
  else if (country == "India") minsMonth*indiaPaygI
  else if (country == "USA") minsMonth*usaPaygI
  else {
    if (country == "Mexico" && lineType == "Y") minsMonth*mexicoPaygMl
    else if (country == "Mexico" && lineType == "N") minsMonth*mexicoPaygL
    else if (country == "UK" && lineType == "Y") minsMonth*ukPaygMl else minsMonth*ukPaygL
  }
}
    println(s"Your projected cost per month is $cost")
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I think case classes is a good starting point for your imporvements

Comment: I'd consider case classes and pattern matching deconstructions.

Comment: Maybe you can try posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, they should be able to give you some more detailed pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean things up quite a bit with just simple pattern matching:

```
object callingCost {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //user input
    print("Will you be using (1)Monthly or (2)Pay-As-You-Go ")
    val planType = readInt()
    print("What country will you be calling? ")
    val country = readLine()
    print("How many minutes would you talk per month? ")
    val minsMonth = readInt()
    print("Will you be calling both Mobile and Landlines as opposed to just landlines? (Y/N) ")
    val lineType = readLine()

    //declare monthly subscription cost per country
    val cost = (planType, country, minsMonth, lineType) match {
      case (1, "China", m, _) if m <= 120 => 1.19
      case (1, "China", m, _) if m <= 400 => 3.89
      case (1, "China", m, _) if m <= 800 => 7.79
      case (1, "China", _, _)             => 13.99
      case (1, "India", m, _) if m <= 120 => 1.42
      case (1, "India", m, _) if m <= 800 => 8.99
      case (1, "India", _, _)             => 19.99
      case (1, "UK", _, "Y")              => 2.09
      case (1, "UK", _, _)                => 1.19
      case (1, "Mexico", _, _)            => 1.79
      case (1, "USA", _, _)               => 2.99
      case (2, "China", m, _)             => m * 0.02
      case (2, "India", m, _)             => m * 0.015
      case (2, "USA", m, _)               => m * 0.023
      case (2, "Mexico", m, "Y")          => m * 0.035
      case (2, "Mexico", m, "N")          => m * 0.01
      case (2, "UK", m, "Y")              => m * 0.10
      case (2, "UK", m, _)                => m * 0.023
    }

    println(s"Your projected cost per month is $cost")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @adrice727 that is perfect!!!! It also allows me to now understand cases. It’s not easy learning just from a book! You totally made my night of studying worth it.